# JTable appears smaller

Tags: java, swing, jtable, null-layout-manager

I created a table using JTable but it appears smaller than the panel as you see in the picture bellow ...

[image]

the code is

```
            tableModel1 = new DefaultTableModel(data1,column_header1);

            table_1 = new JTable(tableModel1);
            JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(table_1);


            scrollPane1.setBounds(1, 1, 1050, 500);
            panel_3.add(scrollPane1);
```

Comment: What is the layout manager on `panel_3`? It should probably be `BorderLayout` and you should be adding the scroll pane at `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Answer (score 2):

We really need to know the layout manager you are using on "panel_3". The best place to put a JScrollPane is in the CENTER position of a BorderLayout. This is because the CENTER position gets all remaining space. If you resize the window it will grow/shrink as necessary.

On panel_3 set your layout to BorderLayout. Then add your JScrollPane to the CENTER position:

```
panel_3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel_3.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then remove that call to setBounds().

Answer (score -1):

I Assume your jtable contents are fit to jpanel.. Try to add more rows in the jtable so that vertical scrollbars can possibly appear. Technically vertical/horizondal scroll bars appears on neccessary situation . In your case no possibility of vertical scrollbar since you have only 4 rows and no horizondal also since your columns width are fit to the panel width... Add the property in your code and verify..

```
scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```